# protobuf-net deserialize kth element in a serialized array

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I am writing an array of integers at position `pos` in a stream. I basically have an `int[]` and I use `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, array, typeof(int[]), PrefixStyle.Fixed32, -1);`. This appends to the stream the array with the correct prefix length.

I want to deserialize elements from the stream at random indices. One way could be to seek into the stream by `pos + (index*fixedLength)` but I notice the integers in this array are written using `DataFormat.Default` which yields a varient-length encoding.

Is there a way to change this?

I can see one way of doing this is to encapsulate the array as a property in some wrapper class. Then I could specify the `DataFormat.FixedSize` in the attribute. Is this the best practice for such scenario?

Also what would `fixedLength` be? `sizeof(int)`?

Thanks,
Iulian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, if all you want is fixed sized integers in a file (or any other stream), there is absolutely no benefit using protocol buffers; forget that - just write your integers as 4-byte chunks (little-endian is probably most convenient), and access them directly from the file (/ stream). Protocol buffers makes working with *structured* data easy, but that doesn't mean you should use it for every job. In this case, it makes absolute sense to just use raw offsets.

Comment: Yes this is definitely true for how the question was expressed :). However, I was only trying to simplify the actual problem. I will mark this as the answer and post another much more detailed question. Thank you, Iulian

Comment: @lulian let me know when you add the more complete question

Comment: Thank you Marc - I posted the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951775/protobuf-net-lazy-streaming-deserialization-of-fields).