# Protobuf-net lazy streaming deserialization of fields

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

**Overall aim**: To skip a very long field when deserializing, and when the field is accessed to read elements from it directly from the stream without loading the whole field.

**Example classes** The object being serialized/deserialized is `FatPropertyClass`.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class FatPropertyClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private int smallProperty;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private FatArray2<int> fatProperty;

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    private int[] array;

    public FatPropertyClass()
    {

    }

    public FatPropertyClass(int sp, int[] fp)
    {
        smallProperty = sp;
        fatProperty = new FatArray<int>(fp);
    }

    public int SmallProperty
    {
        get { return smallProperty; }
        set { smallProperty = value; }
    }

    public FatArray<int> FatProperty
    {
        get { return fatProperty; }
        set { fatProperty = value; }
    }

    public int[] Array
    {
        get { return array; }
        set { array = value; }
    }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class FatArray2<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.FixedSize)]
    private T[] array;
    private Stream sourceStream;
    private long position;

    public FatArray2()
    {
    }

    public FatArray2(T[] array)
    {
        this.array = new T[array.Length];
        Array.Copy(array, this.array, array.Length);
    }


    [ProtoBeforeDeserialization]
    private void BeforeDeserialize(SerializationContext context)
    {
        position = ((Stream)context.Context).Position;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            // logic to get the relevant index from the stream.
            return default(T);
        }
        set
        {
            // only relevant when full array is available for example.
        }
    }
}
```

I can deserialize like so: `FatPropertyClass d = model.Deserialize(fileStream, null, typeof(FatPropertyClass), new SerializationContext() {Context = fileStream}) as FatPropertyClass;` where the `model` can be for example:

```
    RuntimeTypeModel model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
    MetaType mt = model.Add(typeof(FatPropertyClass), false);
    mt.AddField(1, "smallProperty");
    mt.AddField(2, "fatProperty");
    mt.AddField(3, "array");
    MetaType mtFat = model.Add(typeof(FatArray<int>), false);
```

This will skip the deserialization of `array` in `FatArray<T>`. However, I then need to read random elements from that array at a later time. One thing I tried is to remember the stream position before deserialization in the `BeforeDeserialize(SerializationContext context)` method of `FatArray2<T>`. As in the above code: `position = ((Stream)context.Context).Position;`. However this seems to always be the end of the stream.

How can I remember the stream position where `FatProperty2` begins and how can I read from it at a random index?

**Note**: The parameter `T` in `FatArray2<T>` can be of other types marked with `[ProtoContract]`, not just primitives. Also there could be multiple properties of type `FatProperty2<T>` at various depths in the object graph.

**Method 2**: Serialize the field `FatProperty2<T>` after the serialization of the containing object. So, serialize `FatPropertyClass` with length prefix, then serialize with length prefix all fat arrays it contains. Mark all of these fat array properties with an attribute, and at deserialization we can remember the stream position for each of them.

Then the question is how do we read primitives out of it? This works OK for classes using `T item = Serializer.DeserializeItems<T>(sourceStream, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag).Skip(index).Take(1).ToArray();` to get the item at index `index`. But how does this work for primitives? An array of primitives does not seem to be able to be deserialized using `DeserializeItems`.

Is `DeserializeItems` with LINQ used like that even OK? Does it do what I assume it does (internally skip through the stream to the correct element - at worst reading each length prefix and skipping it)?

Regards,
Iulian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question depends an awful lot on the *actual* model - it isn't a scenario that the library specifically targets to make convenient. I suspect that your best bet here would be to write the reader manually using `ProtoReader`. Note that there *are* some tricks when it comes to reading selected items if the *outermost* object is a `List<SomeType>` or similar, but internal objects are typically either simply read or skipped.

By starting again from the root of the document via `ProtoReader`, you could seek fairly efficiently to the nth item. I can do a concrete example later if you like (I haven't leapt in unless you're sure it will actually be useful). For reference, the reason the stream's position isn't useful here is: the library aggressively over-reads and buffers data, unless you specifically tell it to limit its length. This is because data like "varint" is hard to read efficiently without lots of buffering, as it would end up being a lot of individual calls to `ReadByte()`, rather than just working with a local buffer.

---

This is a **completely untested** version of reading the n-th array item of the sub-property directly from a reader; note that it would be inefficient to call this lots of times one after the other, but it should be obvious how to change it to read a *range of consecutive values*, etc:

```
static int? ReadNthArrayItem(Stream source, int index, int maxLen)
{
    using (var reader = new ProtoReader(source, null, null, maxLen))
    {
        int field, count = 0;
        while ((field = reader.ReadFieldHeader()) > 0)
        {
            switch (field)
            {
                case 2: // fat property; a sub object
                    var tok = ProtoReader.StartSubItem(reader);
                    while ((field = reader.ReadFieldHeader()) > 0)
                    {
                        switch (field)
                        {
                            case 1: // the array field
                                if(count++ == index)
                                    return reader.ReadInt32();
                                reader.SkipField();
                                break;
                            default:
                                reader.SkipField();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    ProtoReader.EndSubItem(tok, reader);
                    break;
                default:
                    reader.SkipField();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Finally, note that if this is a large array, you might want to use "packed" arrays (see the protobuf documentation, but this basically stores them without the header per-item). This would be a lot more efficient, but note that it requires slightly different reading code.  You enable packed arrays by adding `IsPacked = true` onto the `[ProtoMember(...)]` for that array.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what is happening with the stream. I do have one question though - how do you limit the buffer size? An example of how to skip to the correct field would indeed be very useful in this scenario.

Comment: @lulian see edit for example, including length limiting; note the length limit is optional

Comment: This works. I have 2 more questions though. 1. How do you read an element from a packed array using `ProtoReader`? 2. If it is not an array of primitives, how do you recommend reading from an index? Using `DeserializeItems<T>(...).Skip(index)` or manually with `ProtoReader`?

Comment: @lulian 2: depends on a few things. Note that if you pass the model into the reader, the methods to deserialize a sub-object are exposed, so you don't need to do it all manually. 1: see the first part (where there is a packed wire type) here: https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Serializers/ArrayDecorator.cs